# What technology could I expect to exist in the year 3000 A.D.?

Tags: technology, technological-development, science-in-society, scientific-development, far-future

A list of different technology would be nice

Comment: Isn't this what Futurama explored for seven seasons? Smelloscopes, the Robot Devil, interstellar mini-golf, dark-matter starship fuel, etc.

Comment: Really impossible to tell, as possibilities range from the human race going extinct around 2500 AD on up through various forms of techno-wizardry.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should at least specify an area your are interested in for ex robotics/genetics/AI etc...

Comment: sticks and stones if there's any trees to make sticks from left

Comment: As others have pointed out, your question is overly broad. As such, it has made it to the low quality review and might be closed unless you [edit it](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/77765/edit) to add more information. You need to give a much more defined question where you limit the question to a much smaller one - as others suggested, ask for a specific field and then, if you want to, you can ask new questions for other fields.

Comment: I can't even say what kind of technology could we expect from the XXIIth century...

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If your question gets put on hold you can still edit it. After a few edits the question can be reopened once it fits the sites guidelines. Please have a look at the help center regarding ["What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) for moer information. Have fun!

Comment: I want that list too!

Comment: You are limited only by your imagination (and perhaps some laws of physics) I recommend thinking of specific technologies you want for your story and then coming back to us with questions about their feasibility.

Comment: Consider people imagined nuclear-powered flying cars and different ways to read the newspaper. Meanwhile, nobody saw the iPhone coming. That was 50 years ago. I don't imagine people in the Middle Ages had a better guess.

Answer (score 3):

The leading advisor on this exact time period is [quoted](http://www.metrolyrics.com/year-3000-lyrics-busted.html) as saying

> I've been to the year 3000
>
> Not much has changed but they lived underwater
>
> And your great, great, great-granddaughter is pretty fine (Is pretty fine)

Given the difficulties of moving underwater I can only predict that either some nuclear war made deep sea living more attractive or perhaps global warming flooded the world.

For more information see the insightful (foresightful?) [quote](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/beatles/yellowsubmarine.html) from a group of men who also probably have about as good a guess as anyone and have been known to say:

> We all live in a yellow submarine
>
> Yellow submarine, yellow submarine

With the added prediction:

> As we live a life of ease (A life of ease)
>
> Everyone of us (Everyone of us) has all we need (Has all we need)

Clearly stating technology has increased to the point where all our needs are catered for.

As far as I can tell this is about as much as we can say on the topic.